# Regex: How to dynamically get words after the first word and not the last word in a '_' separated string?

Tags: regex, preg-match

Working on a migrations class in php.
If I have a string like this:

```
create_users_roles_table
```

and I want to get the words between the first and the last word correctly, plus being able to get the word correct if there's only one word inbetween like:

```
create_users_table
```

How do I go about that?

I've done:

```
(\B)_([a-zA-Z]+)_?([a-zA-Z]+)_table
```

and that works fine when I do **create_users_roles_table**
and produces **users** and **roles**.
But when only doing **create_users_table** it produces **user** and **s**.
Obviously I need it to produce only **users**.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should read

```
(\B)_([a-zA-Z]+)_?([a-zA-Z]+)?_table
```

But this won't work if there are three words in between. I'd suggest stripping the words and then splitting them separately, since I don't think regular expressions can handle variable number of capture groups.

If you can be sure of how many words there can be, you can always hard code this. For tree or less words you can use

```
(\B)_([a-zA-Z]+)(?:_([a-zA-Z]+))?(?:_([a-zA-Z]+))?_table
```